# Longest sequence of minimally finer topologies part 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Suppose we start with a topology $T_1$ of X. Is there a way to get construct a sequence of topologies $T_n$ such that $T_{n - 1} \subset T_{n}$ in which there is no finer topologies in between, also that sequence is the longest one‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌. But now I am restricting each successor to be unique that is if that is $T_{n + 1}$ is the only possible successor for $T_n$.

I think in this case we will only have only a sequence of length two.

Comment: For context, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468266/longest-sequence-of-minimally-finer-topologies) is the original question.  Note that at the end of my answer there I give an example of a sequence of length two where $T_2$ is the only possible successor of $T_1$.

Comment: Alright thank you I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniqueness isn't possible -- consider $ X = \{0, 1\}, \tau_0 = \{\emptyset, X\}$. $\tau_0$ has two incomparable minimal refinements: 
$\tau_{1,0} = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, X\}$ and $\tau_{1,1} = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\}$. They're homeomorphic (both are Sierpinski space) though the topologies differ.

But minimal refinements need not be homeomorphic – consider $Y = \{0, 1, 2\}$, $\tau'_0 = \{\emptyset, Y\}$. Two non-homeomorphic minimal refinements: $\tau'_a = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, Y\}$ and $\tau'_b = \{\emptyset, \{0, 1\}, Y\}$.